# List of files from SVN with full path

Tags: svn

*I want to get list of files with full path from SVN repository.*
By using the command(`svn list -R 192.0.0.0/Project/BRANCH1`) . I am getting list of files  with full path but it is displaying as `parentfolder` then `parentfolder/subfolder`.
For example , I have svn repository as  `192.0.0.0/Project/BRANCH1`

In that Branch1 I have file like `success.jsp`. By using the command(`svn list -R 192.0.0.0/Project/BRANCH1`)
   It is displaying as `BRANCH1/`   then 
                       `BRANCH1/success.jsp`.

Here i want simply as `BRANCH1/success.jsp`.

Also I used (svn list) command to get list of files but,
 It is simply displaying as the folder name of the filebranch (`BRANCH1`)  not that jsp page name. It is displaying as `BRANCH1` 
                                                                                              I want to display as `BRANCH1/success.jsp`

Could you please any one help me  to get list of files from svn with full path by using svn commands.

Comment: WHY ARE WE SHOUTING?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following command line already helps you. It removes all lines from the output, that end with the character '/', i.e. it removes directories.

```
svn ls -R | grep -v '/$'
```

If you need more control, I recommend using the option `--xml` and processing the output with a script. For example, the following python script prints the full pathname of all files, when invoked with `svn ls -R --xml | /tmp/filter.pz`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import sys, lxml.etree
document = lxml.etree.parse(sys.stdin.buffer)
for entry in document.xpath('//entry[@kind="file"]'):
    print(entry.xpath('string(name)'))
```